Python - Keep the trailing zeros on a float value
I'm writing a function that takes a number, it can either be a float or an integer, and returns an integer indicating how many significant figures that number has.
Here is an example
>>> import calculate_number_of_significant_figures
>>> calculate_number_of_significant_figures(3500)
2

Following the rules of significant figures we can conclude that every trailing zero on a floating value is significant:
3.500 has 4 significant figures
2.7400000 has 8 significant figures
and so on...
I know Python understands that 3.500 and 3.5 are equal numbers, they are just represented differently.
Given the context above, when I convert the float value to a string for manipulation and checking purposes python cuts off the trailing zeros:
>>> floating_value = 2.5000
>>> str(floating_value)
'2.5'

I would like the trailing zeros to be kept when performing this conversion.
Am I missing something?
Notes: I know that python has the format placeholder %{}.xf to specify the decimal places, where x is the number of decimal places. But that's not useful for my context since we have rules for defining significant figures.
There is also the decimal library that can handle floating point arithmetics and things related, but I wasn't able to find a solution through the library since it does the same thing as converting to a string (maybe I'm doing something wrong)
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(2.500)
2.5


https://pyformat.info/

The float type doesn't have any facility for tracking precision.  You need to use a different type or track the precision yourself in parallel using a different variable.

As you explained, the number of valid digits is not a property of the number, but of the printed or string form of the number, of how you write it down. So for input numbers you have to keep the number as string and analyze it, for outputs you need to keep track of the error of the computation to then convert the final uncertainty into valid digits and the corresponding string representation.

When it comes to floating numbers, there is "precision" involved and what you see is not exactly what is in the memory.
For example, you can have trailing zeros in the float, but it is not mathematically precise:
Example
import decimal

floating_values = [2.5000, 2.500100, 2.5010000, 2.500011, 2.50011100, 2.50011100000110000]

nums = [f'{val:.64f}' for val in floating_values]
deci = [decimal.Decimal(val) for val in floating_values]

for num, dec in zip(nums, deci):
    print(num)
    print(dec)



Prints
2.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2.5
2.5001000000000002110311925207497552037239074707031250000000000000
2.500100000000000211031192520749755203723907470703125
2.5009999999999998898658759571844711899757385253906250000000000000
2.500999999999999889865875957184471189975738525390625
2.5000110000000002052900072158081457018852233886718750000000000000
2.500011000000000205290007215808145701885223388671875
2.5001109999999999722319898864952847361564636230468750000000000000
2.500110999999999972231989886495284736156463623046875
2.5001110000010999812047884915955364704132080078125000000000000000
2.5001110000010999812047884915955364704132080078125

Note

Decimals makes calculations a bit more precise, if you set precision. But, still that's not mathematically precise.

For instance, for 2.500100, we have 2.5001000000000002110311925207497552037239074707031250000000000000 and this may even differ in your machine from my machine.


